# Usage of to と in this children's book

Tags: particle-と

I've been trying to improve my Japanese by translating a children's book. I only studied Japanese for a short while over 10 years ago so my grammar knowledge is very flawed and I've never read books before, only manga, so I mostly only know the basic grammar used in everyday conversations.

> 「どうしてないているの？」**と**るるちゃんがきく**と**、
>   「おさんぽをしていたら、おうちにかえれなくなったの。」
>   **と**ちいさなおばけはこたえました。

I'm confused to the use of と here. All three of them. I can understand what it says without knowing, but I really want a better understanding the usage of と here.

Answer (score 1):

The と's after the quotations are the quotative case particle ([引用]{いんよう}の[格助詞]{かくじょし}).

> 「どうしてないているの？」**と**るるちゃんがき(いた)
>   "Why are you crying?" asked Ruru-chan.
>
> 「おさんぽをしていたら、おうちにかえれなくなったの。」**と**ちいさなおばけはこたえました。
>   "I lost my way home while taking a walk," replied the little ghost.

The と in 聞くと is a conjunctive particle ([接続助詞]{せつぞくじょし}) for "If" or "When". (This と attaches to the terminal form ([終止形]{しゅうしけい}) of a conjugatable word ([活用語]{かつようご}).)

> るるちゃんが聞く**と**、～～
>   **When** Ruru-chan asked, ~~

Answer (score -1):

The first and third ones are "that": The ghost said that ...
The second one is "and" or perhaps more like "then": Lulu asked ..., then the ghost ...

The second と can be rewritten to すると without changing the meaning like this: 「どうしてないているの？」とるるちゃんがききました。すると、 「おさんぽ...